# setting up xcode4.5 to reference other dylibs

Tags: xcode, dylib

I am new to xcode IDE and having difficulty referencing dylibs.

I am trying to call Matlab runtime initialization function by linking to libmwmclmrt.7.16.dylib and I added that in Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries
Also added the directory which contains the dylibs
*/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v716/bin/maci64* to

Runpath Search paths
Framework Searchpaths
Library Search Paths

in both Project and Target Build settings.

The compilation succeeds but when I run the program that calls the function mclInitializeApplication() I get the following error

"An Error has occurred while trying to initialize the MCR.
The error is: Fatal error loading library /usr/local/lib/libmx.dylib Error: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libmx.dylib, 9): Library not loaded: **libtbb.dylib**
  Referenced from: /Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v716/bin/maci64/**libut.dylib**
  Reason: image not found

I learnt that otool can provide info on dylibs and I verified that libmx.dylib is referencing various other dylibs in 
/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v716/bin/maci64/

```
> otool -L libmx.dylib 
libmx.dylib:
    @rpath/libmx.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libmwresource_core.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libmwi18n.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libut.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libmwfl.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libmwMATLAB_res.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libboost_date_time.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libboost_thread.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libicudata.44.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.2.0)
    @rpath/libicuuc.44.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.2.0)
    @rpath/libicui18n.44.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.2.0)
    @rpath/libicuio.44.dylib (compatibility version 44.0.0, current version 44.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 123.0.0)
```

I have all the required dylibs in the expected location, why am I still getting unable to reference, image not found error

```
$ pwd
/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v716/bin/maci64
$ ls -lrt libtbb.dylib 
-r-xr-xr-x  1 bakkiraju  admin  487912 Jul  8  2011 libtbb.dylib

$ ls -lrt libu
libuij.dylib  libut.dylib   

$ ls -lrt libut.dylib 
-r-xr-xr-x  1 bakkiraju  admin  1217088 Jul 26  2011 libut.dylib
```

Copying these files into /usr/local/lib makes the error go away. How can I configure the
xcode so that references to theses required dylibs start working correctly. I dont want to copy them into /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Under build settings, beyond adding the library path to **Build Settings>Linking>Runpath Search Path**, you also must add the same path to **Build Settings>Search Paths>Library Search Paths**.

I just started using XCode and linking with libraries (the MATLAB ones in particular) has not been straightforward (although, once you get the hang of it, it is much easier than writing Makefiles, in my opinion). I wrote a quick tutorial over on the MATLAB message boards: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31073-tutorial-for-libmat-under-xcode-4-2